# The "php" plugin does not exist drupal 8

Tags: plugins, drupal

I have strange issue in Drupal 8 that says:

> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "php"
>   plugin does not exist. in
>   Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 57 of
>   core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).

Anyone know how to fix this?